# How to get multiple row from single row for data separated by some character on single select statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How to get unique multiple rows from single row for data separated by some character on single select query without split function in **SQL Server 2008** or above.

**Example** :

```
ID  Data                                                Name
1   '2014-01-01,2014-01-02,2014-01-03,2014-01-04'       'A1'
2   '2014-01-01,2014-01-02'                             'B1'
3   '2014-01-03,2014-01-05,2014-01-06,2014-01-07'       'A1'


ID  Data            Name
1   '2014-01-01'    'A1'
1   '2014-01-02'    'A1'
1   '2014-01-03'    'A1'
1   '2014-01-04'    'A1'
3   '2014-01-05'    'A1'
3   '2014-01-06'    'A1'
3   '2014-01-07'    'A1'
2   '2014-01-01'    'B1'
2   '2014-01-02'    'B1'
```

Comment: It may help [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this SQL Sentry article on string splitting.  If goes over the different techniques, speed of each one and any pitfalls.

http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Split the string and take a distinct values.

The code below uses the xml spliter.

```
-- Just playing
use tempdb;
go

-- drop the table
if object_id('results') > 0 
drop table results
go

-- create the table
create table results
(
  id int,
  data varchar(128),
  name varchar(2)
);
go

-- add data
insert into results values
(1,'2014-01-01,2014-01-02,2014-01-03,2014-01-04','A1'),
(2,'2014-01-01,2014-01-02','B1'),
(3,'2014-01-03,2014-01-05,2014-01-06,2014-01-07','A1');
go

-- Just the data
select * from results

-- Split the data
select distinct r.id, r.name, s.item 
from results r 
cross apply dbo.SplitStrings_XML(data, ',') s
```

[image]